# Is there a size restraint for background image for standard tile data?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to create a secondary tile with `StandardTileData`:

```
StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData()
{
    Title = "",
    BackgroundImage = new Uri("/wifi.png", UriKind.Relative)
};
```

But the `BackgroundImage` is not set, are there some size restrictions? Do the image have to have a certain property set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image size is not the problem here, it's the file location.

Your [`BackgrounImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.standardtiledata.backgroundimage%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) image has to be saved into shared folder:

> If the URI references an image that was stored in isolated storage,
>   then **the image must be in the `Shared\ShellContent` folder**. For more
>   information, see [Data for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).